# spark-jobServer 0.8.x SQL examples

Tags: spark-jobserver

I have installed spark-observer v 0.8.0 with Scala 2.11. I am able to run examples from job-server-tests. However Im unable to find any examples related to running SQL ( load some file/create temporary table and then run SQL against this table). Do I run job-server or job-server-extras? Im running job-server using SBT.
sbt>reStart

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have tried sbt>job-server-extras/reStart.   and then run:   curl -d "" '127.0.0.1:8090/contexts/sql-context?context-factory=spark.jobserver.context.SQLContextFactory'.   Im getting class not found exception.